# Elasticsearch equivalent to "SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve some documents where the name matches certain conditions. These conditions are important as they contribute to the scoring mechanism, allowing only the most relevant products to be returned.

However, I do not want documents with the same value for the 'name' field to appear in the search results, and that can happen a lot, since with equal names they would have the same score.

I have attempted to use aggregations, which successfully retrieve distinct names and even provide the count of their occurrences in the results. However, the aggregation results do not consider the scores generated by the query's matches. As a result, the returned names are usually the most commonly occurring ones, rather than the names that best match the input, but I expected distinct names with the highest score.

Comment: It should be possible to aggregate also the score (with max, for example) and order by the aggregation.

Comment: check aggregate cardinalty